# Bad root on Galaxy S7 needs unrooting

Tags: 7.0-nougat, unrooting, samsung-galaxy-s7

So I'm not sure exactly what happened, but Dr. Fone by Wondershare seems to have messed up my root.

I'm on a Galaxy S7, Android 7.0 with Nougat.

My phone is acting like it's rooted (VoLTE icon and "hurricane" symbol in the notifications bar, "unauthorized actions" notification appearing) and when I plug it back in to Dr. Fone, it tells me it's rooted and gives me no option to unroot.
But when I open any root checkers or unroot apps on the phone, it says it's not rooted so I can't undo it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was able to un-root (and later re-root successfully) using the [Kingo Android Root (PC Version)](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-remove-root-from-android.htm) which runs in Windows and roots/unroots via a USB cable to the phone with a different process than the on-phone apps.

I hope you were aware before you started that there's always a chance that root will "break" your phone, rendering it useless from then on.  (Hopefully this isn't the case for you.) There are also a lot of downsides to rooting; certain apps and features that become unusable (not the "free for all" I was originally lead to believe.)